# XNA Loading Models

Tags: c#, xna

I am pretty new to the 3D side of XNA and am converting a 2D game. 
Its basically designed as a grid and I am drawing with the code below. This works but is a bit laggy, am I doing this completely wrong? Presumably there shouldn't be much lag at this point when we are only talking about a few small models.

```
 protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        fpsTimer += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime;
        fpsCount++;
        if (fpsTimer >= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        { fpsTimer = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0); fps = fpsCount; fpsCount = 0; }

        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, device.Viewport.AspectRatio, 1.0f, 1000.0f);
        world = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
        view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(xPos, yPos, zHeight), new Vector3(xPos, yPos + zRotation, 0), new Vector3(0, 5, 0));

        // DRAW OBJECTS ON MAP
        drawMap(view, world, projection);

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "" + fps, new Vector2(100, 100), Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }


private void drawMap(Matrix view, Matrix world, Matrix projection)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
        GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
        GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearWrap;

        int scale = Globals.scale;

        int screenWidthScale = Globals.screenwidth / scale;
        int screenHeightScale = Globals.screenheight / scale;

        int mapXtile = Convert.ToInt32(xPos/2);
        int mapYtile = Convert.ToInt32(yPos/2);

        for (int i = Convert.ToInt32(xPos/2) - 30; i < Convert.ToInt32(xPos/2) + 30; i++)
        {
            for (int a = Convert.ToInt32(yPos/2); a < Convert.ToInt32(yPos/2) + 50; a++)
            {
                if (mapXtile > 0 && mapYtile > 0 && mapXtile < Globals.mapsizex && mapYtile < Globals.mapsizey)
                {
                    int currentTile = Globals.levelArray[mapXtile, mapYtile].TyleType;

                    // DRAW TREES
                    if (currentTile == tyleType.tree)
                    {
                        if (Globals.levelArray[mapXtile, mapYtile].typeModifier == 1)
                        {
                            Matrix worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateScale(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f) * Matrix.CreateRotationX(1.5f) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(i * 2 + 0.2f, a * 2 - 0.4f, -0.1f));
                            tree.Draw(worldMatrix, view, projection);
                        }
                        if (Globals.levelArray[mapXtile, mapYtile].typeModifier == 2)
                        {
                            Matrix worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateScale(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f) * Matrix.CreateRotationX(1.5f) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(i * 2+0.2f, a * 2-0.4f, -0.1f));
                            tree2.Draw(worldMatrix, view, projection);
                        }
                    }
                }
                mapYtile = mapYtile + 1;
                //mapYtile++;
            }
            mapXtile = mapXtile + 1;
            mapYtile = Convert.ToInt32(yPos / 2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you really need to reset the `BlendState`, `DepthStencilState` and `SamplerState` every `Draw` call?